# Taking a value from another column if column value == "character(0)"

Tags: r, data.table

In the following data:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
entry <- c("P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR] - Movimiento Bolivia Libre [MBL] [MNR-MBL])",
           "P18-Socialist Party (Partido Socialista [PS])",
           "P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])",
           "")
something <- c(1,2,3,4)
x <- str_match_all(entry, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])") %>% map(drop)
Election_Parties <- tibble::tibble(x, something, entry)
```

I would like to replace the `character(0)` value with the value from a different column like this:

```
setDT(Election_Parties)[identical(x, character(0)) ,x := entry]
```

This however gives me the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(Election_Parties), identical(Election_Parties[,  : 
  LHS of := must be a symbol, or an atomic vector (column names or positions).
```

What am I doing wrong?

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
entry <- c("P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR] - Movimiento Bolivia Libre [MBL] [MNR-MBL])",
           "P18-Socialist Party (Partido Socialista [PS])",
           "P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])",
           "4")
something <- c(1,2,3,4)
x <- str_match_all(entry, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])") %>% map(drop)
Election_Parties <- tibble::tibble(x, something, entry)
```

Comment: Replace `Election_Parties[,1]` with `x`, `Election_Parties[,3]` with entry for a start. Inside a data.table, you should refer to columns by their (unquoted) names, not by referencing the table and the column index.

Comment: There is no `character(0)` in your example, check `identical(character(0), "")` which yields `FALSE`.

Comment: The expression `character(0)` is a vector of length zero. You cannot have that as a column value.

Comment: I tried to do `setDT(Election_Parties)[x=="character(0)" ,x:= entry]` instead, but it makes R crash

Comment: @42- So what do I do then?

Comment: You could explain _what_ you are attempting rather than showing failing code.There is no character(0) value in a dataframe or data.table.

Comment: @42- if you look at the 1st columns 4th value, it is `list(character(0L))`. I think that's pretty easy to conflate with `character(0L)`.

Comment: There is a character(0) value in the fourth entry of the `x`-list. What are you attempting to replace it with?

Comment: Another column value  (`entry`), but at this point literally anything that does not make my R crash.

Comment: I added the actual data, see EDIT

Comment: `entry` is a 4-element character vector from which the x list was derived. It does not see sensible to assign the entire initial vector to the fourth entry of x. Do you want the fourth element of x to be a particular one of those values? If so, then how is the program supposed to determine which single value?

Comment: Again. Describe in natrual language what is desired rather than showing failing code.

Comment: @42- He means the value from entry which corresponds to the row where the condition is met.

Comment: In the actual data I tried to extract everything between brackets into a separate column. Some extractions did not lead to a match and created `character(0)`. If there is no match I would like to have the party description instead of the abbreviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the character(0) values in a list named, `x` with the corresponding entries from a vector of the same length:

```
x[ sapply(x, length)==0 ] <- entry[ sapply(x, length)==0 ]
x
#----------------------
[[1]]
[1] "MNR"     "MBL"     "MNR-MBL"

[[2]]
[1] "PS"

[[3]]
[1] "LJ"

[[4]]
[1] ""
```

This could then be successfully converted into a tibble, data.table, or dataframe which I think is the goal.

In a way, the character(0) values (or non-values) in lists correspond to the role that NA's play in vectors. Lists can also hold NULL values or NAs . Trying to use either `identical` or '==' was failing because those functions are not vectorized for list arguments. Also trying to use "==" with character(0) also runs into problems akin to those with NA's and "==". Running  `character(0) == character(0)` does not return `TRUE` but rather `logical(0)`. Testing for length == 0 is also sometimes needed in `if (  )` conditional expressions.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much for still trying to help, despite my apparently not very clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Election_Parties[,1]` with x, `Election_Parties[,3]` with entry for a start. Inside a data.table, you should refer to columns by their (unquoted) names, not by referencing the table and the column index. The introduction to data.table is [here](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html). Second, `identical()` is not a vectorized function, which means you can't use it in the i-slot. For example,

```
identical(c(1, 1), c(1, 2))
# FALSE
```

Vectorized equality comparison should happen with `==`. If we look at `?"=="`, we see the following:

> At least one of x and y must be an atomic vector, but if the other is a list R attempts to coerce it to the type of the atomic vector: this will succeed if the list is made up of elements of length one that can be coerced to the correct type.

So we can't do an equality comparison between two lists, as you are attempting. In my mind, I was thinking maybe `x == list(character(0L))` would work, but the quote above indicates it won't.

What you're really interested in is "does the list have a positive length". We can check this for each row of `x` like so.

```r
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
entry <- c("P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR] - Movimiento Bolivia Libre [MBL] [MNR-MBL])",
           "P18-Socialist Party (Partido Socialista [PS])",
           "P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])",
           "")
something <- c(1,2,3,4)
x <- str_match_all(entry, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])") %>% map(drop)
Election_Parties <- tibble::tibble(x, something, entry)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose

Election_Parties[[1]]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "MNR"     "MBL"     "MNR-MBL"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "PS"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "LJ"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> character(0)

setDT(Election_Parties)
# Check lengths of x -- we want to modify zero-length pieces.

Election_Parties[,lengths(x)]
#> [1] 3 1 1 0
Election_Parties[lengths(x) == 0, x := entry]
Election_Parties[[1]]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "MNR"     "MBL"     "MNR-MBL"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "PS"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "LJ"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] ""
```

EDIT: The crash is caused by an encoding issue. I solved it by changing the last line to

```r
dt[lengths(x) == 0, x := iconv(entry, sub = "")]
```

This will remove bytes which are causing a problem -- potentially characters 
you want to keep to exactly match entry. I think fixing it completely is perhaps beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The solution makes my R session crash however :S

Comment: Runs fine in mine. What is the result of `packageVersion("data.table")`?

Comment: It's version 1.12.6

Comment: That's the version I have as well. I have updated my example to the exact set of code I ran in a new session. See if that still crashes it.

Comment: Your example does not create a crash. Not sure how to go from here..

Comment: I added the actual data in my post. See EDIT.

Comment: Tom, see my edit. I've answered your original problem and provided enough detail to ask another question if my answer is not quite sufficient to the new problem :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Also for explaining what I was, without much succes,  trying to explain. Weirdly enough, my R still crashed, also when using your EDIT. `42-`'s solution worked luckily, so maybe it is not really worth the effort to understand why it still does not work. Weird though.. Again, thank you very much!